# Can an attacker install an app that takes a name similar to a legitimate app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I know that Apple wants a new app to have a unique name if it is to be registered on the App Store (Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153572/can-two-different-app-with-the-same-name-exist-in-app-store). I have a questions what if an attacker can install an app with the same name as that of a legitimate app. I am assuming an attacker has taken control over the iPhone by some sort of attack such as TrustJacking. I tried searching over the internet but couldn't find anything relevant to answer my question.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless the iPhone is already compromised (jailbroken).  In a normal usage scenario apps are digitally signed with private certificates and so even if an attacker created a new app with the same bundle Id & name, the app wouldn't be launched by iOS; the attacker would also have to somehow find a way to inject the app on your device, which in theory should also be locked. Safe to say that unless proven otherwise, its impossible.

Comment: That being said, if the device is in their physical possession, and they somehow figured out your passcode or faked your biometrics, then they could potentially install a root certificate and have their own signed version of the app.  The ruse wouldn't be very efficient if you noticed that the app was different so they would have to install a near identical version of the app you are likely to launch.

Comment: I agree, any sort of attack would be terribly inefficient. Perhaps 5 years ago this was an issue but these days the security of the device and OS are generally of a very high standard.

Comment: Does it mean that a phishing attack in which a user mistakenly install an app (that) cannot have the same name? I am assuming the device is not in physical possession of the attacker.

Comment: No a phishing attack is out of the question.  Installing a root certificate is a rather complex process and any user would realize its not a simple App Store install.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the display name which shows under the icon, then the answer is yes, that does not have to be unique.

Comment: I am a little confused @ekscrypto is saying that the app cannot have the same name. Can we set a different display name and app name? Which one is used when we search the App store. I would think it is the display name.

Comment: The name in the App store and the name that is displayed under the icon on the homescreen can be different from each other. While the name in the App store has to be unique, the name on the homescreen does not have to be unique.